# Trying to echo H2 tags around statement

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want a title statement wrapped in an h2 tag. I was expecting this to be simple, but it echoes the h2 tags after the title. Such that it shows up in the following way:

The code I'm using:

```
echo "<h2>".the_title()."</h2>";
```

The result:

```
title
<h2></h2>
```

How can I  correct this behavior and ensure the echoed title ends up between the h2 tags?

Comment: What does `the_title()` do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hate WordPress.  You have several options http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title:

```
the_title('<h2>', '</h2>', true);
```

Or:

```
echo "<h2>" . the_title(null, null, false) . "</h2>";
```

Or http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title:

```
echo "<h2>" . get_the_title() . "</h2>";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just write:

```
the_title();
```

The title is output - even without the `echo`! That's because outputting it is a side-effect of `the_title`. This is horrible programming design, in my opinion, but that's how they've chosen to do it.

So when you write:

```
echo "<h2>".the_title()."</h2>";
```

PHP is going:

- Process the expression:

  - `"<h2>"`
  - concatenated with...
  - the return value of `the_title()`

    - call `the_title()` -- this outputs the title!
    - return value: `null`
    - cast `null` to string: `""`
  - concatenated with...
  - `"</h2>"`
- Result: `title goes here<h2></h2>`

You can try:

```
echo "<h2>"; the_title(); echo "</h2>";
```

But I'm fairly sure there's a function that just returns the title rather than outputting it, just check the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `the_title` function to `return` a string instead of `echo`ing or `print`ing it.

Alternatively, output the three strings separately.

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Comment: This is how it's done. No need to hate Wordpress just because you don't know how it works.

Comment: Who's hating WordPress?

Comment: @Quentin: Other people answering the question, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

This seems the cleanest to me

```
<?php the_title('<h1>');?>
```